# How to retrieve the first value in a multi-column listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Here it the listview element in XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="jobsListView_manageajob" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="488" Margin="39,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="jobsListView_manageajob_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobNumberListView1}" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobNameListView1}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I need to retrieve the currently selected item from only one row

```
private void jobsListView_manageajob_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          searchTextBox_manageajob.Text = Convert.ToString(jobsListView_manageajob.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated, I am so stuck!

Comment: what you got in `searchTextBox_manageajob.Text` with current code?

Comment: { JobNameListView1 = Cerner, JobNumberListView1 = 5001 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast selected item object to the actual model type, then get it's property of interest :

```
var myModel = (ClassName)jobsListView_manageajob.SelectedItem;
searchTextBox_manageajob.Text = myModel.JobNameListView1;
```

Comment: What would I type in for ClassName?

Comment: your model class, the one that has property `JobNameListView1` and `JobNumberListView1`. Or if you used anonymous type, cast to dynamic : `(dynamic)jobsListView_manageajob.SelectedItem`

Comment: Thank you har07, this fixed my program. I can now load the rest of the variables now that I know which job the user wants to edit